# Теряются данные ответа Socket Server

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте!
Динамические данные (данные которые сервер шлёт не по запросу на открытый поток клиента) не приходят на клиент. Точнее приходят, если пошевелить поток. Также я вырубил сервер и пошевелил поток. Данные пришли с мертвого сервера. Отсюда вывод, что они приходят но не обрабатываются. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Под "пошевелить" я подразумеваю вызвать следующим образом:

```
 newTransmission("test", null, false)
```

Первый раз я подключаюсь к серверу:

```
newTransmission("test", "ip", true)
```

При чем, сервер пишет в файл что данные успешно отправлены, а клиент тупо не принимает. Данные сервер может отправить в любое время.

```
public void newTransmission(final String msg, final String ip, final boolean newConnect) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //if (type.equals("server-msg-history")) {
            try {
                if (newConnect) {
                    client = null;
                    client = new Socket(ip, 12864); 
                    client.setSoTimeout(1000); // пробовал и без этого
                    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); 
                    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream()); 
                }
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msg);
                ddServerAnswer = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                tvInf.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ddServerAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            try {
                                JSONArray jaAnsw = new JSONArray(ddServerAnswer);
                                switch (jaAnsw.getString(0)) {
                                    case "player-id":
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You player id: " + jaAnsw.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        player_id = jaAnsw.getInt(1);
                                        currentPlayer = (TextView) findViewById(jaAnsw.getInt(1));
                                        break;
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {}
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

                new DenDroidTools().createFile(ddServerAnswer, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dendroid"), "test_client_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
                //dataInputStream.close();
                //dataOutputStream.close();
                //client.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //UnknownHostExceptionErr = "true";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //UnknownHostExceptionErr = "io";
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка: IOException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не пробовали использовать DatagramSocket? Его можно и как клиент и как сервер использовать, по мне так идеальное решение вашей проблемы.